# Return calculated column values for SELECT DISTINCT query

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, distinct, calculated-columns

I have the following table in SQlite:

> _id|token|status  |timestamp|mood|eta|name|calc_eta
>   __________________________________________________________________________ 168|iqmC.3aHMBGbl|ok|1516625084498|50|-4154|Sample Name|1516625533082
>   169|iqmC.3aHMBGbl|ok|1516625084498|50|-4214|Sample Name|1516625533108
>   170|iqmC.3aHMBGbl|ok|1516625084498|50|-4274|Sample Name|1516625533414
>   171|iqmC.3aHMBGbl|ok|1516625084498|50|-4334|Sample Name|1516625533160
>   172|iqmC.3aHMBGbl|ok|1516625084498|50|-4394|Sample Name|1516625533680
>   173|iqmC.3aHMBGbl|ok|1516625084498|50|-4420|Sample Name|1516625533068
>   174|iqmC.3aHMBGbl|ok|1516625084498|50|-4428|Sample Name|1516625533482
>   175|iqmC.3aHMBGbl|ok|1516625084498|50|-4483|Sample Name|1516625533155
>   176|iqmC.3aHMBGbl|ok|1516625084498|50|-4543|Sample Name|1516625533148
>   177|TFbintkHMBw4H|ok|1516630122485|50|2526|Sample Name|1516632672019
>   178|TFbintkHMBw4H|ok|1516630122485|50|2520|Sample Name|1516632671903
>   179|TFbintkHMBw4H|ok|1516630122485|50|2460|Sample Name|1516632672321
>   180|TFbintkHMBw4H|ok|1516630122485|50|2344|Sample Name|1516632672859
>   181|TFbintkHMBw4H|ok|1516630122485|50|2336|Sample Name|1516632671939
>   182|TFbintkHMBw4H|ok|1516630122485|50|2281|Sample Name|1516632672802
>   183|TFbintkHMBw4H|ok|1516630122485|50|2220|Sample Name|1516632671828
>   184|TFbintkHMBw4H|ok|1516630122485|50|2161|Sample Name|1516632672625

I'm trying to come up with a query on it that would give me the difference between the two newest(based on auto-increment *_id*), *calc_eta* values for each distinct *token* value.

So in this case the result should be:

> iqmC.3aHMBGbl|-7
>
> TFbintkHMBw4H|797

I got this far with the SQL but it is not providing the calculated value for each distinct token currently and I'm not sure how to go further.

```html
SELECT DISTINCT token,

  (SELECT calc_eta
   FROM DATA s
   WHERE
       (SELECT count(*)
        FROM DATA f
        WHERE f.token = s.token
          AND f._id >= s._id) <= 1) -
  (SELECT calc_eta
   FROM
     (SELECT calc_eta,
             MIN(_id)
      FROM DATA s
      WHERE
          (SELECT count(*)
           FROM DATA f
           WHERE f.token = s.token
             AND f._id >= s._id) <= 2)) AS delay
FROM DATA;
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

In most SQL dialects, you would use window functions such as `lag()`:

```
select d.*,
       (calc_eta - prev_calc_eta) as diff
from (select d.*,
             lag(calc_eta) over (partition by token order by _id) as prev_calc_eta,
             row_number() over (partition by token order by _id desc) as seqnum
      from data d
     ) d
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: HI Gordon, 
Thanks for this, unfortunately it is for SQLite3 and from what I can gather, window functions are not implemented. Could it be implemented without using these?